# Worst time complexity of a BST (traversing it postorder )

Tags: search, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory, tree-traversal, postorder

Consider the time complexity of a post-order traversal on a binary search tree of `N` nodes. I know it takes `O(N)` to visit all the nodes, in the general case, but what is the complexity in the worst case, when BST is a list? I think it takes `O(N^2)`, because it will traverse `N` nodes to go reach the end, and `N` nodes to go back to the start. That means `N*N = N^2`, so I think it is `O(N^2)`. Is it right?

Comment: You may should consider adding an example of what you understand as a *traversal* on the BST. As it is stated, you're visiting all the nodes, and going back, which leads to `n + n` steps, or `O(n)` in complexity. Notice this empties the meaning of *worst*, as the only case you have is when you traverse all the nodes, and back. (What is *worse* than what here?)

Answer (score 2):

In your "worst case" scenario (which I don't understand, frankly) it's N + N = O(N), not N * N = O(N^2).

Comment: Thank you very much!I'm at the 1st year at CS university and i have not done algorithm complexity yet, so i don't know very well this stuff.Thank you again Ernest!